# Knative-eventing broker scalability

Tags: scalability, broker, knative-eventing

I am looking into Knative-eventing. The architecture in the [official documentation](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/) and the [broker specs](https://github.com/knative/specs/blob/main/specs/eventing/control-plane.md#broker-lifecycle) doesn't seem to provide a clear explanation about why the Broker is not a single point of failure. Could somebody please explain how the Knative-eventing would scale to support a large number of events and possibly point me at some reference that could look into?